# How to use sheet name in formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

Would like to use a cell content within the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('W35'!$H:$H,A21,'W35'!$I:$I))
```

Where W35 is the sheet name.

I would like to set a cell value to be W35 and use it within the above formula.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(INDIRECT(W35&"!H:H"), A21, INDIRECT(W35&"!I:I")))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It may that I did not explain properly what I need. In need to replace the W35 (which is a sheet name) with a text value that I will take from a cell. By doing this, I will put in that cell the sheet name (e.g. W35). the purpose for that is to have the ability to copy paste this formula using different values that corresponds to all the sheets I have (from W1-->W52)